# oil leak over tappet cover of suzuki swift 92

Tags: oil-leak

I have a Suzuki swift 93. I recently changed its piston rings, clutch and pressure plates, and a few other small things. i didn't do the whole engine. Now the engine leaks/spews a little oil from the rubber pipe that joins the tappet cover and the air filter. What could be the reason?

Comment: poor joint on that pipe?

Answer (score 2):

The rubber hose that runs from the rocker cover to the air filter will be part of the PCV system. It's possible that the new piston rings were installed incorrectly leading to excessive crackcase pressure.